# Leer archivo XML en C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

Buen día, actualmente estoy tratando de leer un fragmento de un archivo XML para serializarlo y procesarlo posteriormente.

Cuento con dos archivos XML diferentes que tienen un formato muy parecido. Con el primero de ellos no tengo ningún problema procesando su información; sin embargo, con el segundo no puedo recorrer el archivo correctamente.

**Fragmento de código para leer y procesar las transacciones del primer XML**

```
<LoteRequest
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fecha>2019-05-29T09:00:02.228343Z</fecha>
    <listaTransacciones>
        <transaccion>
            <idProducto>77520052</idProducto>
            <idTransaccion>1556222478097</idTransaccion>
            <moneda>PEN</moneda>
            <importe>5.5</importe>
        </transaccion>
    </listaTransacciones>
</LoteRequest>
```

---

```
XmlDocument document = FrameHandling.StringToXml(input); // input -> string XML

foreach(XmlNode node in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("listaTransacciones/transaccion")) 
{
    // Serializa nodo transacción
}
```

**Fragmento de código para leer y procesar los parámetros del segundo XML**

```
<DirectoRequest
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<fecha>2019-03-22T14:30:00Z</fecha>
<idProducto>77520043</idProducto>
<listaParametros>
    <parametro>
        <ordinal>2</ordinal>
        <valor>950228954</valor>
    </parametro>
    <parametro>
        <ordinal>3</ordinal>
        <valor>5</valor>
    </parametro>
</listaParametros>
</DirectoRequest>
```

---

```
XmlDocument document = FrameHandling.StringToXml(input); // input -> string XML

foreach (XmlNode node in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("listaParametros/parametro"))
{
    // Serializa nodo parametro
    // A pesar de que el código para recorrer cada "parametro" es correcto, el loop nunca es ejecutado
}
```

Espero alguién pueda darme algunos tips para resolver este problema.
Gracias.

Comment: Es muy extraño, me he llevado tal cual tu código a otro proyecto y funciona perfectamente, lo único que he cambiado ha sido la forma de cargar el `XmlDocument` ya que he utilizado el comando `Load` del mismo objeto, puedes echarle un vistado al código en mi [GitHub](https://github.com/RublenX/StackOverflow/tree/master/RublenX.RespuestasRapidas/ConsoleAppFrk/Questions/273458)

Comment: Que es el FrameHandling ? es alguna libreria de terceros para trabjar xml

Comment: @JuanRu, gracias por tu respuesta, me funcionó a la perfección.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias deserializar el xml usando clases, entonces defines

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="parametro")]
public class Parametro {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="ordinal")]
    public string Ordinal { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="valor")]
    public string Valor { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="listaParametros")]
public class ListaParametros {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="parametro")]
    public List<Parametro> Parametro { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="DirectoRequest")]
public class DirectoRequest {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="fecha")]
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="idProducto")]
    public string IdProducto { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="listaParametros")]
    public ListaParametros ListaParametros { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsd", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xsi", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
}
```

Te puede ayudar con

[xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Para despues deserializar

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<DirectoRequest
                        xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
                        <fecha>2019-03-22T14:30:00Z</fecha>
                        <idProducto>77520043</idProducto>
                        <listaParametros>
                            <parametro>
                                <ordinal>2</ordinal>
                                <valor>950228954</valor>
                            </parametro>
                            <parametro>
                                <ordinal>3</ordinal>
                                <valor>5</valor>
                            </parametro>
                        </listaParametros>
                        </DirectoRequest>";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DirectoRequest));

        DirectoRequest result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
           result = (DirectoRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("id:{0} Parametros:{1}", 
                                        result.IdProducto, 
                                        string.Join(", ", result.ListaParametros.Parametro.Select(x=>x.Valor)));
    }
}
```

de esta forma accedes a los datos por medio de la `class` y la `List<>` de los parametros